# Constructed model in Pyomo and trying to uso gurobi solver in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, gurobi

I constructed a model using pyomo in google colab, this is my interest. The model is too large.
When I use the following code, it returns an error saying that I require a full license to use gurobi solver:

```
...model constructed with pyomo.....

#solve the pyomo model:
opt = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python")
out = opt.solve(model)
```

I do not want to create the model within the Gurobi environment. I already created it with pyomo, I just want to use the solver. So I requested a WLS license in gurobi.com.
Now with the credentials in hand, I tried the following code as instructed in [gurobi website](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409582394769-Google-Colab-Installation-and-Licensing#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20https%3A%2F%2Flicense,you%20can%20access%20it%20directly.):

```
...model constructed with pyomo.....

#SOLVING THE PYOMO MODEL:
############# IF USING GUROBI SOLVER (CONVEX APPLICATIONS - LINEAR, CONIC OR QUADRATIC)############
!pip install gurobipy pyomo
import gurobipy as gp
params = {  # Create an environment with your WLS license
"WLSACCESSID": 'STRING INPUT',
"WLSSECRET": 'STRING INPUT',
"LICENSEID": INT INPUT,
}
env = gp.Env(params=params)

# Create the model within the Gurobi environment
#model = gp.Model(env=env)
model = gp.Model(env=env)
#solver: gurobi
opt = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python")
out = opt.solve(model)
```

But as I said before, I do not want to create using Gurobi Environment so it seems this code is overwritting my original pyomo model, and the following error persists:

```
`
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: gurobipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (10.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyomo in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (6.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ply in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pyomo) (3.11)
Set parameter WLSAccessID
Set parameter WLSSecret
Set parameter LicenseID to value "my license"
Academic license - for non-commercial use only - registered to "my email"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-230-bd70bd49a037> in <cell line: 28>()
     26 #solver: gurobi
     27 opt = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python")
---> 28 out = opt.solve(model)
     29 
     30 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/direct_or_persistent_solver.py in _set_instance(self, model, kwds)
    183                 "'_presolve' method must be a Model or a Block".format(type(self))
    184             )
--> 185             raise ValueError(msg)
    186         self._pyomo_model = model
    187         self._symbolic_solver_labels = kwds.pop(

ValueError: The problem instance supplied to the <class 'pyomo.solvers.plugins.solvers.gurobi_direct.GurobiDirect'> plugin '_presolve' method must be a Model or a Block
`
```

Please, what should be the code to solve my constructed pyomo model?
THANKS!

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you should pass [a Pyomo model to the `SolverFactory`](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/working_models.html), not Gurobi's `gp.Model`.